# How can I open .bazel file extensions in IntellijIDEA rather than XCode?

Tags: intellij-idea, bazel

All other file extensions are opening in IntellijIDEA except .bazel. I'm sure there is a way to open this in Intellij IDEA as well.

Comment: Have you installed "Bazel" plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Settings (Ctrl+Alt+S) > Editor > File Types`
2. Add a file type using the `+` button
3. Add a pattern - `*.bazel`

Or install the bazel plugin